# Not working Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference

Tags: java, android, textview

I have searched my case but i cant find a proper answer im newbie here and its still not working so **please help me...**

Here is my code...

```
TextView TotalAmount;
int total_amount = 0;
RecyclerView dayrecyclerView;
List<Day_Details> DL;
Day_Adapter dayAdapter;
public static List<Day_Details> daysize;

 TotalAmount = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.event_total);
    TotalAmount.setText(String.valueOf(total_amount));
  public void Day(List<Day_Details> dyl) {
    //List<Day_Details>dayDetailsList

    Log.i("day response length", "dayresponse length " + dyl.size());

    if (dyl.size() > 0) {
        daysize = dyl;
        daylayout.setVisibility(LinearLayout.VISIBLE);
        DL = new ArrayList<>();
        dayAdapter = new Day_Adapter(this, DL);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        dayrecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        dayrecyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        dayrecyclerView.setAdapter(dayAdapter);
        dayrecyclerView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                return true;
            }
        });
        for (int i = 0; i < dyl.size(); i++) {
            String price = "₹ " + dyl.get(i).getDayPrice();
            Day_Details DD = new Day_Details(dyl.get(i).getId(), 
            dyl.get(i).getDayTitle(), dyl.get(i).getDayDate(), price, 
            dyl.get(i).getDayContent());
            Log.i(" Event_view ", "Day: Details "+DD.toString());
            DL.add(DD);
        }

        dayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }


}
 public  void daychecker(Boolean ischecked,String id){

if(ischecked == true){
    for (int i = 0; i <daysize.size(); i++) {
        if(id == daysize.get(i).getId()){
           String price = daysize.get(i).getDayPrice();
           int amount = Integer.parseInt(price);
            total_amount = total_amount + amount;

        }
    }
    TotalAmount.setText("1234");
}else{
    for (int i = 0; i <=daysize.size(); i++) {
        if(id == String.valueOf(i)){
            String price = daysize.get(i).getDayPrice();
            int amount = Integer.parseInt(price);
            total_amount = total_amount - amount;
            TotalAmount.setText(String.valueOf(total_amount));
        }
    }
}
}
```

The days is in recyclerview
when i check the checkbox it passes an id and price 
i have to show that price in that **textview**(TotalAmount)
so when i click in checkbox it shows error as

```
04-25 11:27:29.366 9462-9462/com.appeonix.dithesh.doceventUI E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                           Process: com.appeonix.dithesh.doceventUI, PID: 9462
                                                                           java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
                                                                               at com.appeonix.doceventUI.Activity.UI.Event_View$override.daychecker(Event_View.java:258)
                                                                               at com.appeonix.doceventUI.Activity.UI.Event_View$override.access$dispatch(Event_View.java)
                                                                               at com.appeonix.doceventUI.Activity.UI.Event_View.daychecker(Event_View.java:0)
                                                                               at com.appeonix.doceventUI.Activity.Holder.Day_Holder$1.onClick(Day_Holder.java:39)
                                                                               at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5184)
                                                                               at android.widget.CompoundButton.performClick(CompoundButton.java:128)
                                                                               at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:20910)
                                                                               at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5942)
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1400)
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1195)
```

here is  my Oncreateview

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.event_view_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);


    sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("DocEventPreference", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    memid = sharedPreferences.getString("DocId", null);
    scrollView = (NestedScrollView) findViewById(R.id.Event_view_Scroll);
    //team
    teamrecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.team_recycler_view);
    //gallery
    galrecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.galleryrecycler_view);
    //day
    dayrecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.dayrecycler_view);

    //details
    About = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.abouttheevent);
    //qrcode
    imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.qrCode);
    //register
    TotalAmount = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.event_total);
    TotalAmount.setText(String.valueOf(total_amount));
    registerlay = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.registerlayout);
    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Event_reg_confirm_btn);
    scrollView.post(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            scrollView.fullScroll(scrollView.FOCUS_UP);
        }
    });
    events_details = new Events_Details();
    events_details.setId(event_id);
    eventitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Event_Name);
    Event_IMG = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.backdrop);
    //LinearLayout
     eventgallerylayout = (LinearLayout) 
    findViewById(R.id.EventView_Gallery);
    eventdetailslayout = (LinearLayout) 
    findViewById(R.id.EventView_Details);
    daylayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.EventDay_Details);
    eventteamlayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.EventView_Team);
    eventQRlayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.EventView_Qrcode);
    //        eventregisterlayout = (LinearLayout) 
    findViewById(R.id.EventView_Register);
    eventdetailslayout.setVisibility(LinearLayout.GONE);
    button.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    eventteamlayout.setVisibility(LinearLayout.GONE);
    daylayout.setVisibility(LinearLayout.GONE);
    eventgallerylayout.setVisibility(LinearLayout.GONE);
    //        eventQRlayout.setVisibility(LinearLayout.GONE);
   //        eventregisterlayout.setVisibility(LinearLayout.GONE);
    SingleEventJavaWebservice webservice = new SingleEventJavaWebservice(
            Event_View.this, events_details, Event_View.this);
    webservice.execute();

    initCollapsingToolbar();
}
```

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please check your xml layout that id "event_total" is proper or not in below line:

```
  TotalAmount = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.event_total);
```

Answer (score 0):

@Dithesh Could you please check using debug that the TextView to which you are assigning value is initialized in that method. Also please check the String.valueOf(total_amount) returns a proper string value.

Comment: i have passed 6000 in String.valueOf(total_amount) at returns properly.. but at that time the textview in null i dont know why.. i have intialize at the begin...

Comment: DayChecker method is called from your activity? Just for testing call this method after your TextView initialization

Comment: Initialization of TextView is looking fine. Check to see if you are getting error at second line.If you dont get error your textview is properly initialized.

 TotalAmount = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.event_total);
  TotalAmount.setText(String.valueOf(total_amount));

Answer (score 0):

Your initialization of textview should be in onCreate()

> TotalAmount = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.event_total);

That's what is causing the error.

**Edit as per your updated question**

The initialization looks fine so you should check the layout file 'event_view_main.xml' if it contains a TextView with id 'event_total'

Comment: That's not compulsory we can initialize it anywhere we want

Comment: @HarshSinghal yes we can initialize views outside of onCreate but that can be done only in lifecycle methods which executes after onCreate. Because this is where we inflate the layout and without the layout the view won't get initialized and will throw NPE. Please read [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html)

Comment: i have put the oncreate view section... please check it and tell me whats wrong in that

Comment: @DitheshVishalakshan check if the TextView with id 'event_total' exists in layout file 'event_view_main.xml'

Comment: actually it is include from another xml into the event_view_main layout..so is there any problem with that

Comment: That shouldn't be the problem then. I think you should consider editing the question and merging the two parts of code together (as it seems that they belong to the same .class file) also add the related xml files as well. That might be helpful for others to help you.

Comment: @ChetanAshtivkar i have added xml..can u check that

Comment: Can't see the xml file. Do check. Also you should consider merging the code as well as it belongs to the same file.

Answer (score 0):

if you don't initialize the TextView then it throw a null Pointer Exeption
you should initialize the TextView when the Activity is Created.